# Xamarin.Forms project cannot be opened in VS2013 after install VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project based on the shared template and VS2013.
I first have updated my machine from Win 8.1 to Win 10.
After doing that, I have tested the projects to my VS2013 installation. All projects including the .forms project have worked without problems.
Then I have installed VS2015 (unter Win 10).
After doing that, I cannot open my .forms-project unter VS2013 anymore.

Error message (translated to English):
Title: Check changes on project and solution.
This projects are not supported or there are changes needed that influences the project behavior so that the projects can be opened in this version of Visual studio.
Changes are automatically applied, so that the behavior is not influenced.

Not supported:
- Android-project
- iOS-Project

So… it seems as something from the VS20**15** installation causes this error message in VS20**13**.

**What do I have to do, to bring my project unter VS2013 to work again?**

Comment: By my investigations, it seems, as the Xamarin integration software to VS2013 was - why ever - removed by the install of VS2015. I now try to bring my VS2013 to work again (reinstall the correct IS version to VS2013). I write here again, if I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done...
First, I have tried to remove the VS2013 add-on package “Get Xamarin” and reinstall the add-on package "Xamarin" (what - I think so - should be the new name of the Xamarin integration SW package).
This has **not** worked...
The installation then have crashed and showed a form with download-links for each piece of SW (including the Integration-SW Xamarin V3.11.1589).
I then have downloaded only the **.msi to V3.11.1589** and started it.

By the setup, I was able to select the VS-Version where to install the SW (selected VS2013 as under VS2015 the SW already was installed).
After the installation, I was able again to open my project under VS2013 without error-message.
As I only had the chance to install the newest IS version and the newest V3.11.1589 have dependencies on the MAC (MAC OS at least Mac OS X 10.10.5, XCode at least 7, Xamarin.iOS at least 9.1), I was not able to connect to the MAC BH and had to update the MAC first to XCode 7.1 and the latest Xamarin Studio (about 4,5 gig to install).

After doing that, I have rebooted the MAC and also my PC, un-paired and re-paired the MAC Build Host with my PC and then was able to work again with my VS2013 installation.

**Conclusion:**

- It seems, as the installation of VS2015 **with Xamarin** (at least on Win
  10) **removes** an already installed Xamarin on an already installed
  VS2013, so that the Xamarin projects cannot be opened anymore.
- If VS2015 is installed (with Xamarin option), the Xamarin Integration SW **V. V3.11.1589** is
  installed to VS2015 (today). This is also the latest “stable”
  release on the Xamarin page (but I don’t have found a dedicated
  download-link for the .msi on the Xamarin pages).
  So… as I think, that for VS2015 the
  latest “official” version should be used, I think, you also should
  install the latest version for the older VS version (so that you are
  able to develop with the “old” VS version but also to migrate your
  project to VS2015 what should be the target normally).
- But, if you want to use this version (V3.11.1589) you also have to update XCode and Xamarin Studio on the MAC (what - depending on your Internet
  connection - can take a few hours).

**So… if you have the same problem, I suggest you to:**

- Search for the .msi to V3.11.1589 and install it (select only your “old” VS-Installation in the setup). 
  As I don’t have found a download link, I have posted in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/163882/#Comment_163882) (I think that an answer from Xamarin with a download-link should be added soon)
- Update the MAC to XCode 7.1 and Xamarin Studio to the latest stable version (Xamarin.iOS, Version: 9.1.0.27)
- Unpair the Build Host in the MAC
- Reboot MAC and your development PC
- Re-Pair the Build Host

**After doing that, my VS2013 installation (Xamarin.Forms project) now works again.**

Comment: Um.. [and reinstall the add-on package "Xamarin"] has bogged down for me; it takes me to the Xamarin download webpage, gets vstoolsforxamarin.exe and promptly launches the 2015 updater. I've got no way to touch 2013 anymore. Also trued looking for [Integration-SW Xamarin V3.11.1589] and got 4 results, 2 of which were this page.